# SQLSTATE[42000] Error

Tags: php, sql

Cant figure out where this query is going wrong...

getting this error:

```
{"databaseException":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) \n    VALUES (1, array)' at line 1"
```

from this query

```
$statement = $db->prepare(
"INSERT INTO `descriptions` (vrm, desc) VALUES (:vrm, :description)"
);

if ($statement->execute(array(
':vrm' => '1', 
':description' => $_POST['desc'])));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add backticks to the `desc` column name. It's a reserved word (ORDER BY vrm DESC).

Comment: ah thought it was that! Thanks!